# QGIS 2.14.4 attribute table fields not visible in Statist plugin

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I had one point shapefile to which I joined new numerical attributes by a csv text file.

I saved it by right clicking and everything works fine, I use it for calculations etc.

But when I use the "Statist" plugin, the new fields are not visible.
The fields are visible in the properties tab of the shapefile and they are noted as qlonglong type (Typename: Integer64, Lenght: 10, Precision: 0).

Any idea why this might happen?

Comment: what version of the plugin are you using? (You can find this out using Plugin Manager). Have you tried upgrading the plugin to the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that the **Statist** plugin does not recognise the `qlonglong` type fields but does recognise `integer` fields.

So you could create a new field using the **Field Calculator** and copy over the values using the name of the `qlonglong` field as the *expression*.